# How to pass data from grpc rpc call to server interceptor in java

Tags: grpc, interceptor, grpc-java

I am trying to set some metadata with a value from the response after the rpc server call has been processed. The plan was to use server interceptor and override `close` method.

Something like this: https://github.com/dconnelly/grpc-error-example/blob/master/src/main/java/example/Errors.java#L38

Since the metadata value depends on the response, I need some way to pass data from rpc server call to server interceptor or access the response from interceptor

In  Golang, the metadata can be set easily in the rpc call `grpc.SetTrailer` after processing but in java there is no way to do it in rpc call. So I am trying to use server interceptor for the same.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use grpc-java's `Context`s for that.
In the interceptor you attach a `Context` with a custom key containing a mutable reference. Then in the call you access that header again and extract the value from it.

```java
public static final Context.Key<TrailerHolder> TRAILER_HOLDER_KEY = Context.key("trailerHolder");
    
Context context = Context.current().withValue(TRAILER_HOLDER_KEY, new TrailerHolder());
Context previousContext = context.attach();
[...]
context.detach(previousContext);
```

You can access the context value like this:

```java
TrailerHolder trailerHolder = TRAILER_HOLDER_KEY.get();
```

You might want to implement your code similar to this method:
[`Contexts#interceptCall(Context, ServerCall, Metadata, ServerCallHandler)`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/Contexts.java#L44)

EDIT:

```java
import io.grpc.Context;
import io.grpc.ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall;
import io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener;
import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.ServerCall;
import io.grpc.ServerCall.Listener;
import io.grpc.ServerCallHandler;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptor;
import io.grpc.Status;

public class TrailerServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    public static final Context.Key<Metadata> TRAILER_HOLDER_KEY = Context.key("trailerHolder");

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, final Metadata headers,
            final ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        final TrailerCall<ReqT, RespT> call2 = new TrailerCall<>(call);
        final Context context = Context.current().withValue(TRAILER_HOLDER_KEY, new Metadata());
        final Context previousContext = context.attach();
        try {
            return new TrailerListener<>(next.startCall(call2, headers), context);
        } finally {
            context.detach(previousContext);
        }
    }

    private class TrailerCall<ReqT, RespT> extends SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT> {

        public TrailerCall(final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public void close(final Status status, final Metadata trailers) {
            trailers.merge(TRAILER_HOLDER_KEY.get());
            super.close(status, trailers);
        }

    }

    private class TrailerListener<ReqT> extends ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT> {

        private final Context context;

        public TrailerListener(final ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> delegate, final Context context) {
            super(delegate);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(final ReqT message) {
            final Context previous = this.context.attach();
            try {
                super.onMessage(message);
            } finally {
                this.context.detach(previous);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onHalfClose() {
            final Context previous = this.context.attach();
            try {
                super.onHalfClose();
            } finally {
                this.context.detach(previous);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            final Context previous = this.context.attach();
            try {
                super.onCancel();
            } finally {
                this.context.detach(previous);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            final Context previous = this.context.attach();
            try {
                super.onComplete();
            } finally {
                this.context.detach(previous);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReady() {
            final Context previous = this.context.attach();
            try {
                super.onReady();
            } finally {
                this.context.detach(previous);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

In your grpc service method you can simply use `TRAILER_HOLDER_KEY.get().put(...)`

Comment: Do we have to create new context in rpc call or interceptor? I want to pass data from rpc call to interceptor.

Comment: How do I add some value to the context in my rpc method?

Comment: Added a full example

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. Just one more question, Context is thread safe right?

Comment: AFAICT: `Context`s are immutable and I assume that the method used to set/get the current context are thread-safe.

Comment: In my gRPC service method, “put” is not an option  only “get()” is. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure which "put" you are referring to. There is only `Context#with(Key, Value)` and `Key.get()`. Which might be a little inconsistent, but that's how it is.