# How can I download a .zip file over a http to grpc transcoded endpoint?

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy

I have the grpc endpoint defined as below. The grpc endpoint returns a .zip file. It works OK over a grpc channel, but I'm having issues downloading it over the REST endpoint.

I use envoy to do the http transcoding.

My problem right now, on the REST endpoint, is that the download response header is always set to  application/json instead of application/zip for the zip download to properly work.

Any idea how I can instruct envoy to set the proper headers during transcoding, so that the REST download will properly work ?

```
  // Download build
  //
  // Download build
  rpc DownloadBuild(DownloadBuildRequest) returns (stream DownloadResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get : "/v4/projects/{projectId}/types/{buildType}/builds/{buildVersion}/.download"
      headers: {}
    };
    option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_swagger.options.openapiv2_operation) = {
      description: "Download build.";
      summary: "Download build.";
      tags: "Builds";
      produces: "application/zip";
      responses: {
        key: "200"
        value: {
          description: "Download build";
        }
      }
      responses: {
        key: "401"
        value: {
          description: "Request could not be authorized";
        }
      }
      responses: {
        key: "404"
        value: {
          description: "Build not found";
        }
      }
      responses: {
        key: "500"
        value: {
          description: "Internal server error";
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a way to partially solve my problem. Basically I will have to use google.api.HttpBody as response and set the content type in there.
https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/httpbody.proto

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter#sending-arbitrary-content

I still have a problem with setting the downloaded file name and extension header.

Answer (score 0):

To set the filename header, I had to define a server interceptor, similar to what is mentioned here:

[How to pass data from grpc rpc call to server interceptor in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370763/how-to-pass-data-from-grpc-rpc-call-to-server-interceptor-in-java)

```
  private class TrailerCall<ReqT, RespT> extends SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT> {

    public TrailerCall(final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void sendHeaders(Metadata headers) {
        headers.merge(RESPONSE_HEADERS_HOLDER_KEY.get());
        super.sendHeaders(headers);
    }

}
```